# Place a button in center of screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap, I try to place a button in the center,
I achieve it by finely adjust the grid column by column

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-7">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried `text-center` and `block-center`, they did not work properly.

How to get it done in a straight forward way?

Comment: removing the `col` classes and adding `text-center` works on my end.

Comment: I think @HerrSerker closes your question without give you a correct answer cause you want center your button with Bootstrap and not with CSS.
Simply remove col classes like this

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: Thank you, css is extremely hard, can only be mastered by massive utilization. I am shy prefer bootstrap as a shortcut. @D.Schreier

Comment: You shouldn't be ashame, bootstrap is a good way to save time and be quicker ;)
Enjoy !